# How to setup an access point for two wireless networks of which one ends on a VPN?

Tags: wireless, networking, vpn, openvpn, wireless-access-point

I currently have an Ubuntu machine, which I'd like to use as a access point/proxy server.

Now, due to the requirements I have, it's going to be a fairly complex (for a beginner...) setup.

The machine is connected to the internet, and it has a wireless card.

The end result is that should act as router (access point) for two separate wireless networks.
One network would connect directly to internet, the other instead should connect to a VPN.

I don't know if this is typical or not, but essentially I want all the trusted users to be able to connect to a wireless which goes directly to the internet, while the untrusted ones connect to the internet through a VPN, behind the scenes.

Can anybody give me an overview of the concepts involved, and where can I start studying for setting it up?
The VPN setup should be an OpenVPN one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ready made distributions that take care of your requirements. My personal favorite would be [IPCop](http://www.ipcop.org/docs.php). In essence it is a Linux distribution dedicated to converting your system to a sophisticated, state of the art firewall/router appliance. To get a general idea of what is involved take a look at the documentation (both installation and administration) on the above link.

Another great resource is this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions) that lists (almost all!?!) firewall distributions.